# what does "conformed to the part" mean? does "part" mean "region"?

Tags: meaning

what does "conformed to the part" mean? does "part" mean "region"?

His personality is discussed later in the
chapter upon the Eddy brothers and Mrs. Holmes, to which the reader
is referred. Her earth name had been Morgan, and King was rather the
general title of a certain class of spirits than an ordinary name. Her life
had been spent two hundred years before, in the reign of Charles the
Second, in the island of Jamaica. Whether this be true or not, she
undoubtedly **conformed to the part**, and her general conversation was
consistent with her account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly convoluted, but basically the narrator is saying that he does not entirely believe the story that 'Morgan' is telling, and is suggesting that it might be 'an act'. He is then saying that if so, she is doing a good job of that acting, of 'playing the part'

In other words, `part` means `a particular character within a play`.